# python performance of subsequent call to os.listdir

Tags: python, windows, caching

I'm performing a heavy glob operation on a network drive (a CIFS share on a NAS) from a windows machine.
(CPython, v2.7.6)

The folder "Project" contains 1 To for 15 840 files and 1232 folders.

(I'm usinf the glob module which is calling os.listdir() recursively)

The following script is loaded in IDLE and I'm doing "Run Module" multiple times

```
import timeit
import glob

globPath = u'Z:/Project/*/*/*/*'

def native_glob():
    glob.glob(globPath))

print timeit.timeit(native_glob, number=1)
```

first call:

```
>>> 64.4641505602
```

next and every other call (+- .5 sec):

```
>>> 2.07747177124
```

(The command returns 4125 files)

The first call highly depends on the network charge, it was in a range from 100 sec to 40 sec, but subsequent calls are always around 2 sec each.

It looks like there is a caching mechanism behind this.

- Can anyone reproduce this behavior ?
- Is this only related to windows or is this coming from python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't do any caching of `os.listdir()` calls, this is entirely down to Windows.

Any network directory listing is going to be slow until cached, and folder listings on a remote network-shared drive are no exception.

Comment: So I guess there is no way I could control the way the caching is happening. Is miraculously efficient but the cache is not consistent and I can't know when it's going to be released. I was comparing with a custom made cache but it was always slower (obviously if I'm comparing a dict based cache to a os native caching system)

Comment: You cannot cache what you haven't first retrieved, and caching requires a sparse resource: memory, so the OS can and will clean stuff up to make way for other things more urgently in need of caching for a while. Also, you need to avoid caching too much or too long lest you get outdated information.

Comment: Yes I'm storing the modification time in my cache hierarchy so that I can update it accordingly.